# how do I change the spacing after the References title?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing

I found how to change the spacing between the reference items:

http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20140712-bibtex-spacing.html

But how do I change the spacing between "References" and the actual item? Normally, I would use vspace{-x} (for a normal section), but there is nowhere I specify a section of References in this case, it is automatic.

Comment: This strongly depends on how the bibliography and its heading are produced. This can depend on the bibliography package you use (`natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and also on the document class you use. Can you show us a short example document with a small bibliography, please?

Comment: That all said, usually the heading of the bibliography/references is just typeset as `\chapter`/`\chapter*`/`\section`/`\section*` and so unless you only want to change the spacing for the bibliography (and not for all other headings), the question you should be asking is "how do I modify the spacing after a chapter/section heading?" Again, the answer depends on the document class you use.